# Store data of multiple parsed XML files - .NET

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, parsing

I've been working on a VB application which parses multiple XML files, and create an Excel file from them.

The main problem of this is that I am, simply, reading each line of each XML and outputs them to the Excel file when a specific node is found. I would like to know if exists any method to store the data from each element, just to use it once everything (all the XML files) have been parsed.

I was thinking about databases but I think this is excessive and unnecesary. Maybe you can give me some ideas in order to make it working.

Comment: You can use `System.Xml.XmlDocument` to load an entire XML file into memory, or `System.Xml.XmlReader` to load the XML file as a stream.

Comment: Yes, I did it already. I am using XmlDocument to read, get and save the data into variables. The problem is not parsing the file, but "export" the entirely data avoiding the "read and output" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Data.DataSet` can be used as an "in memory database".

You can use a `DataSet` to store information in memory - a `DataSet` can contain multiple `DataTables` and you can add columns to those at runtime, even if there are already rows in the `DataTable`. So even if you don't know the XML node names ahead of time, you can add them as columns as they appear.

You can also use `DataView`s to filter the data inside the `DataSet`.

My typical way of pre-parsing XML is to create a two-column `DataTable` with the XPATH address of each node and its value. You can then do a second pass that matches XPATH addresses to your objects/dataset.

Comment: It seems exactly what I am looking for! I will investigate everything about DataSet. Thank you.